# ¿ como solucionar un error de Docker a la hora de instalar cualquier proyecto?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hola hace unos dias vengo presentado un error a la hora de instalar un proyecto de Docker alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este error que arroja por consola:

```
PS C:\Users\thefe\OneDrive\Escritorio\bndes_bid_seguranca_publica-main> docker-compose up --build
time="2022-11-09T09:05:50-05:00" level=warning msg="The \"g1\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2022-11-09T09:05:50-05:00" level=warning msg="The \"k7o6990\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2022-11-09T09:05:50-05:00" level=warning msg="The \"g1\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2022-11-09T09:05:50-05:00" level=warning msg="The \"k7o6990\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
Error response from daemon: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2: invalid argument
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿El cual no me permite instalar este proyecto o algunos otros, cuál puede ser la causa de este error??

**Cabe aclarar que no tiene que ver con el código porque hice la prueba de instalación en otro pc pero en el mio no**

Comment: Poner etiquetas aleatorias hace más difícil que te respondan los que realmente saben del tema. Si llegan los que saben un montón de python, no van a ver algo que puedan responder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso es que hay un contenedor corrupto (o varios contenedores corruptos).

Una de dos, o fumigas todo y rehaces los volumenes

```
docker system prune --all
docker volume prune 
docker-compose up
```

O los arrancas uno a uno pa saber cuál falla

`docker-compose up <servicio1> <servicio2>...`

Y ya sabiendo, haces `docker-compose build --no-cache <servicio_roto>`